# Requesting for a new visa

Tags: usa, overstaying, nigerian-citizens, egypt

I overstayed my visa in Cairo for about a year and a half. Can I use the same passport to enter other countries (the USA to be specific), hoping I won't be denied?

Comment: What is your nationality? Do you have entry/exit stamps in your passport showing you overstayed? Why did you overstay? Did you pay a fine on exit? What will you say to US immigration if asked to convince them that you won’t overstay in the US (ie to overcome their presumption of immigrant intent), given you have a history of doing it?

Comment: I'm a Nigerian, I have entry /exit stamps on my passport and I paid my fine for overstaying

Answer (score 3):

Chances are more to get rejected if you overstay in any country. Having said that, it always depends on the person who interviews you for your visa. Some agents will ask really detailed questions and some might just ignore your situation if you have an otherwise good travel history.

Comment: @Kumar Overstaying for 18 months typically doesn’t help anyone demonstrate a ‘good travel history’

Comment: @Traveller I think what he meant is if he has **other** positive travel history.

Comment: Since the question mentions "use the same passport" it might be worth pointing out that getting a new passport will make absolutely no difference whatsoever.